# Widening MOS device leads to subthreshold conduction

Tags: analog

[image]

[image]

Could someone explain why increasing the W/L (hence g_m) would lead to the device eventually going into sub-threshold. I thought by increasing W/L, the current would increase, so we would be further away from sub-threshold if anything.

Comment: Following up - does my answer cover all of your doubts, or is there anything you'd like me to clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remark linking W/L to subthreshold condition directly applies to fig 3.48(b), where the FET is biased by a constant current source. Without loss of generality, I'll keep the length fixed, and talk about changes in width throughout this answer.

In the constant-current case, wider FET and constant current implies that the current density (per micron of width) decreases; this means that the channel needs to be less inverted to achieve the operating point, so the mode of operation approaches and enters subthreshold conduction as W/L increases further.

In integrated circuit designs where you control W/L, you can benefit from this wide W/L in scenarios where you need high gain, high transconductance efficiency, but can live with low speed.

In these integrated circuit scenarios, you're likely dealing with a transistor biased by a constant current anyway, since current mirrors and active loads are cheaper and easier to realize than resistors on many integrated silicon processes.

For 3.48(a), you are correct that increasing W/L with \$V_{gs}\$ held constant would increase the current. However, it wouldn't be *further* from subthreshold in this case; rather same Vgs means same level of inversion in the channel meaning same inversion coefficient, so it's "equally" close to subthreshold as before.

However if you *are* realizing the circuit in 3.48(a) and want to widen your FET, you'll need to reduce Vgs anyway, to prevent the amplifier from saturation. In essence, you're still maintaining roughly constant current through the transistor, just with manual fine tuning or negative feedback, rather than by directly biasing with a current source.